# From DLFileEntry get "/full/path/to/file"

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

In Liferay's Document and Media, I created a folder called `myfolder` containing a folder called `subfolder` containing a file called `file.txt`.

I have the DLFileEntry of `file.txt`.

How to get the string `/folder/subfolder/file.txt`?

Notes:

- Context: For display/reporting purposes, I need to get the full path of the file, a bit like how it would appear in a breadcrumb.
- `getTreePath()` gives identifiers such as `/32701/` instead of folder names
- I greped the whole Liferay 7 DXP SP4 for `getBreadcrumbs` and no source code came, even though a method with this name seemed to exist in Liferay 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation:

```
protected String fullPath(DLFileEntry file) throws PortalException {
    String fileName = file.getFileName();
    DLFolder folder = file.getFolder();

    if (folder == null) {
        return "/" + fileName;
    }
    else {
        return fullPath(folder) + "/" + fileName;
    }
}

protected String fullPath(DLFolder folder) throws PortalException {
    String folderName = folder.getName();
    DLFolder parent = folder.getParentFolder();

    if (parent == null) {
        return "/" + folderName;
    }
    else {
        return fullPath(parent) + folderName;
    }
}
```

All ideas to improve maintainability and performance are welcome!